# Sql Server Data Type Casting

Tags: sql-server, types, casting, sqldatatypes

I'm wondering what the performance impact of the following might be if any.  Let's say there is a table with one of the columns data typed as int.  This table contains millions and millions of rows.  Then lets say the below 2 sql statements are ran.

```
SELECT * FROM tblTest WHERE colInt in (3,4)
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM tblTest WHERE colInt in ('3','4')
```

I believe in the second query the implied character data type will attempt to convert all the values in the colInt and then try to do the comparison.  Can anyone confirm this is how the process works?  Does anyone know of an MSDN article that explains this?  Is this fairly expensive?

I know this seems quite silly however when you are forced to live by it because of third party software there isn't much we can do except fully understand what the implications are going to be when they change the data type of several columns from int to varchar and vise versus.

Answer (score 2):

The more likely scenario is that the optimizer will cast the two literals to INTs.

Comment: I checked it. Joe Stefanelli is right: SQL Optimizer converts second query to first. So, it compares columns with int values, not strings. So performance is good. :)

Comment: That's what I thout at first until I ran a test. Created a table with a Int column. Then changed the column to varchar and added a record with characters then got this error which makes me think its converting all the values in the columns. select * from TestTable where myint in (1,2)... Sql server gave me this error... Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'four' to data type int. This error shouldn't have come up it the where values were converted to varchar, right?

Comment: @user - they are saying it gets converted to `int` so yes, it would come up.  That why he says it `will cast the two literals to INTs`.  Also be aware this is a **TERRIBLE IDEA** - see my answer below.

Comment: They are not converted. SQL Optimizer sometimes uses logic from another planet. But, when your column is int, and you run second query, it converts '3' and '4' to int. I check it with Actual Exectuion Plan: 

[golfcoach].[dbo].[Players].[ID]=(487) OR [golfcoach].[dbo].[Players].[ID]=(488)

Comment: I totally agree this is horrible however it is out of my control.  But my test makes me feel the second query does not get converted tot he first per the test I ran.  I ran the first  query against a table where the column was a int.  Updated column to varchar.  Ran the same query and then I got the converting error which makes me think the literals in the where clause to not get converted to data type in the table but that's not what both of you are suggesting.  Anyway to confirm?

Comment: Don't try to change column type. As I said, SQL Optimizer uses another logic. Just try:
1. Column is int
2. Check in menu "Query" -> "Include Actual Execution Plan"
3. Run second query
In tab "Execution plan" you can see you **actual** execution plan.

Comment: I added a row of character data between running the two sql statements.  Perhaps if you are seeing that it does convert the literals in teh where clause and this test feels like it doesn't... does that mean sql server will decide what to do when it wants to.

Comment: THANK YOU FOR THE LINK.  That answers it!

Comment: > does that mean sql server will decide what to do when it wants to. EXACTLY!

Comment: @JNK. This is in theory. Did you try to run samples and look at execution plan or compare execution time? I check it on the table with 50'000'000+ records - plan and time is the same. I think SQL Optimizer try to convert '3' and '4' to int, it does this successfully, then it compares, what is faster - convert all column's values to string or convert this 2 values to int. And decides to run with 3 and 4 as int.

Comment: @chop `This is in theory` based on what MS tells us.  It's how they say the optimizer operates so I have no reason to question it.

Answer (score 2):

You should run this against your data to see.

However, be VERY VERY cautious when converting from `int` to `varchar` or vice versa.   You will get some unexpected behavior, especially with ordering or inequality operators like `<` and `>`:

```
SELECT 'True'
WHERE 100 < 20

SELECT 'True'
WHERE '100' < '20'
```

`100` is greater than `20`, but `'100'` is less than `'20'` because varchars are compared by the first character first, and `2` is greater than `1`.

It gets even more complicated if you include leading `0`s in your varchars:

```
SELECT 'True'
WHERE 0100 < 020

SELECT 'True'
WHERE '0100' < '0020'
```

The second statement is no longer `True` because `'0020'` is less than `'0100'` since it starts with 2 `0`s.

**Be VERY VERY careful.**